# IE8 - Can't add sites to favorites bar

Tags: bookmarks, internet-explorer-8

I can't add new sites to IE8 Favorites Bar anymore. I can remove already existing sites from the Favorites bar without any problems. It was working before but I can't quite pinpoint the moment when it stopped working.

**The current situation is this:**

- When I click the "Star with the green arrow" (aka Add to favorites bar) button then nothing at all happens - no new bookmark, no errors.
- When I open the "Favorites" menu, click "Add to favorites", select `Create in: Favorites Bar` and click Add then I get this error:

> Unable to create 'example.com':
>
> Unspecified error

[image]
[image]

How could I fix this?

I also tried with `Internet Explorer (No Add-ons)` - the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried dragging a link from the URL bar to the favorites bar?

Comment: @Moab: Tried - it works! Nice workaround though the problem still bugs me. If you add this as an aswer I'll +1 it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to drag a shortcut from the URL bar to the Favorites bar. (this is how I have always done it, just too easy)

You could also try an IE8 reset. Read carefully before doing it, you can lose some IE data in the process.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737

If i was the conspiracy theory type, I would say MS did it on purpose when trying to link to Google. ;-)

.